# Are these created on the heap or stack

Tags: c++

say I have a class as such

```
class foo
{
  private:
  std::string str;
  int a;
  poo* p;

  public:
  foo
  {
     p = new poo();
  }

  void someMethod() {....}
}
```

Now I wanted to know if I go the following ways:

```
foo* f = new foo();
```

or

```
foo f;
```

where would the variables `str`,`a` and `p` be created in each case ?? Are member variables affected by how the class is created ?  For instance I would think that `str` and `a` would be created on the stack and `p` would created on the heap. I would appreciate it if someone could clear this up ..

Comment: I understand that part. Does creating it on heap or stack affect the internal member variables

Comment: @MistyD Yes, it does.

Comment: Don't confuse the pointer `p` with the `poo` object it points at. The former is part of the `foo` object, the latter is always a separate heap allocation.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if the members were put on the stack and then the function returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `poo` instance `p` points to is always located on the heap, the pointer itself though (`p`) is located in/at the `foo` instance.

In the first version (`foo* f = new foo()`) a `foo` instance is created on the heap (including all of its members, they are always at the same place) and the pointer to it (the `f` var) is stored at the stack or in some register (thats up to the compiler).

In the second version the foo instance is located on the stack (including all of its members).

But notice that the actual location of an object is not that important as the actual scope of an object. You should really look up the term RAII.

Comment: You stated that `foo* f = new foo()` creats foo on the heap. I agree with that but then you stated that `str` and `a` are also allocated on the heap. I am having difficulty understanding this. Since `str` and `a` are removed (out of scope) when we delete the instance of f. If they were on the heap wouldnt we have to delete them manually

Comment: `str` and `a` are located where `foo` is, in that case on the heap. If you have an object, all of its members are located in order, top to bottom. So first comes `str` then `a` and then `p` (notice, the pointer `p`, a 32-bit integer on x86). `f` points to the beginning of this group we call an object or instance ;) . They only get "out-of-scope" if the instance itself leaves scope (its kinda confusing to speak of scopes when dealing with heap-allocated instances). That would be the case if you execute `delete f;`. Technically the destructor will call their destructors respectively.

Comment: I want to add a little thing about inheritance here. If you have a relation `class Child : public Parent` than all members of `Parents` are at the top, and below them are the members of `Child`, like they were two seperate objects. That also means that a `Child*` pointer has to be technically "casted" if passed as `this` pointer to a method of `Child` (basically `basePtr + [size of Parent]`). If `Parent` has some virtual methods, a vftable is placed at the beginning, if `Child` has some virtual methods, a vftable is placed at the beginning of the "Child part".

Answer (score 0):

Non-static data members of a class are created there where an object of the class is created.